# Casting string value to enumerated value C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, enums, casting

I have a class `MyClass` which has

```
public enum Days{Mon, Tue, Wed}
```

and then a field

```
public Days dayOfWeek;
```

From another class in my solution I have a string (`myString`) value of either `0`, `1` or `2`. I want to set an instance of `MyClass`'s (called `myClassInstance`) field `dayOfWeek` equal to `myStringvalue` such that `0` means Mon, `1` means Tue...

I have tried

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(myString)
```

and

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = (int) myString
```

but neither work. I'm sure this is straightforward. Why don't these techniques work?

Comment: "Why don't these techniques work?"  Because an enum isn't an int.  You can't set an enum value equal to the value of an int.

Comment: Use DayOfWeek instead of yours Days enum. details here ->  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
string s = "0";
Days day = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), s);
```

or

```
string s = "0";
Days day;
if(!Enum.TryParse(s, out day)) {
    // error handling
}
```

to gracefully handle the case where `s` can't be parsed to an instance of `Days`.

This works per the documentation for [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) which states

> **Converts the string representation of the** name or **numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object**.

Additionally, you can check if the instance of `string` actually represents a value defined by the enum via

```
string s = "3";
bool defined = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Days), s);
// defined is false
```

`Enum.Parse` will blindly parse `s` in this case, even though it doesn't represent a value defined by the enum `Days` and the cast from the result of `Enum.Parse` to `Days` will not fail.

Moreover, there is a built-in enum that represents the days of the week. This enum is [`System.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx). I would suggest using this.

Finally, if for some reason you can't use `System.DayOfWeek`, you should at a minimum rename your enum to `Day` instead of `Days` (remove the pluralization). Only enums that represent flags should be pluralized. Note that the variable `day` above represents a day, and it does not represent days. This is why you should rename the enum to `Day`. This is consistent with the [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that most C# and .NET programmers use.

Comment: Hi, you're right I should of called it Day. Didn't know about pluralising flags though. Makes sense though as flags would be a collection such as Overflow, Zero, Carry, Negative and you'd call it somethign like executeFlags. Anyhow this isn't the actual name of th enum I'm actually implementing ... I've tried to make my question Generic. The problem I have is that the enum is in another class. Despite setting the access modifier to public, I cannot see if from the calling class. That is I cannot have myClassInstance.Days dayOfWeek. It doesn't let me declare this from outside MyClass. Howcome?

Comment: I got it working... I just used MyClass.Days not an instance of it!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to cast the `int` to the `Days` enum after converting it:

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = (Days)Convert.ToInt32(myString);
```

You can also use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) (if you're in .NET 4) or [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx).  Depending on how much your trust the incoming data, you may also want to call [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to make sure that the integer is a valid value of `Days` (otherwise, in all of these cases, you'll have an instance of `Days` that doesn't correspond to any of your named values).

```
Days dayOfWeek;
if (!Enum.TryParse(myString, out dayOfWeek)) {
    dayOfWeek = Days.Mon; // or some other default, or throw
}

myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
```

Or

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), myString);
```

In addition, as others have mentioned, you may want to consider using the built-in [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enum instead of your custom version, if it matches what you really want.

Also, as others have mentioned again, even if it doesn't, `Day` is a better name based on the .NET naming guidelines, since it isn't a [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx#Flags) enum.

Comment: I'm developing for .net 3.5. Anyhow I cannot cast to (Days) because I cannot seem to access the enum inside of myClassInstance, despite setting the access modifier to public.

Comment: If you've defined it inside of `MyClass`, you'll need to use `MyClass.Days` to reference it outside of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = (Days)int.Parse(myString);
```

Do you know there is already an Enum that you can resuse called `DayOfWeek` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Days d = (Days)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), myString);
```

A more complete example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0040__Data-Type/ParseastringtoanenumEnumParse.htm).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx docs say I'm wrong "name or numeric value"

Comment: No, it should work for integers, too. At least, it does in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `int` to `Days`:

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = (Days)Convert.ToInt32(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is cast the string to an int (or tryparse if you want to do it in a nice way)

Then use the Following code to set the enum value:

(Days)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Days), intValue);

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
myClassInstance.dayOfWeek = Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), myString);
```

[Enump.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: the problem is that the definition of Days is stored within MyClass and I cannot seeem to access it. Despite my definition being  public enum Days{ Mon, Tue, Wed }. If I put a static modifier after public, I can access it in another class but my program wont compile as I'm not allowed to put a static in MyClass

Comment: I got it working... I just used MyClass.Days not an instance of it!